# How to know if fetch result .json() will succeed

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch

I'd like to know if there is a safe way to know whether the result of `fetch` can be turned into json with `.json()`, without complaining about there not being a body.

It seems like all APIs I query always include a `body` on the `result` of `fetch`, however, sometimes that body is in fact empty.

I'd like to know whether there is a failproof way to detect that, before I call `.json()` on the result?

```
const result = await fetch();
const parsedResult = result.json(); // This causes multiple errors
```

Sometimes it fails because the result is not JSON, but sometimes it fails because there is no body (apparently), how to detect the second case?

I can of course wrap the `.json()` call inside a try-catch block, but ideally I'd like to avoid calling it altogether.

Comment: You could check the [content type](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/introduction-to-fetch#response_metadata) of the response :)

Comment: Do you check the response code? If it's not a HTP 200 (for example a 500) then the body won't be what you expect. This seems more like a server issue than a client issue

Comment: A well documented API will tell you what you have to expect/check from a response to safely work with it.